# Webpack casing error but file doesnt exist

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I use webpack to see how my website looks like and it is running fine but when I make any changed and save them I get the webpack error: "Error: Prevent writing to file that only differs in casing or query string from already written file.". After a bit of research this error seems to be rather straight forward but my problem is that the files webpack is referring to are files webpack itself has created. The files webpack shows in the error are:
\main\dist\Main.c8f67b0b67a885cb40a7.hot-update.js
and
\main\dist\main.c8f67b0b67a885cb40a7.hot-update.js

There isnt an actual "dist" folder in "main" so I can delete or change one of them. I have already tried adding an "output" object into my webpack.config which didnt help, I tried using "CleanWebpackPlugin" which also doesnt help so I dont really know what else to do.

Making changes to the my web site, save them and then view those changes. Instead webpack threw an error and I need to restart the dev server to view those changes.